# async/await still returns undefined

Tags: javascript, async-await

I would like to **wait until the database return values are complete** and then display them in HTML using a view. Unfortunately, despite `async` and `wait`, I always get the return value

> "undefined".

but the database query returns values as you can see in the console output inside `getSensorData()` function.

```js
app.post("/lesen", async function(request, response){         
    //get ID
    let FzID = request.body.ID;
    console.log(FzID);

    //get Data for ID from DB
    let data = await db.getSensorData(FzID);

    console.log("DB response: " + data);


    //create view
    const body = view.createView(JSON.stringify(data));
    response.send(body);
});
```

```js
//MariaDB
const mariadb = require('mariadb');
const pool = mariadb.createPool({
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 3307,
  database: "mydatabase",
  user: 'myuser',
  password: 'mypasswd',
  connectionLimit: 5,
  connectTimeout: 5000,
  //rowsAsArray: true //Returns result-sets as arrays, rather than JSON.
  //This is a faster way to get results. For more information, see Query.
});

async function getSensorData(data) {
  console.log("MariaDB.getSensorData(" + data + ")...");

  let db;
  try {
    console.log("getConnection()..");
    db = await pool.getConnection();
    const rows = await db.query("SELECT * from sensordaten WHERE UID=?", data);

    console.log("from DB connection:")
    console.log(rows); //[ {val: 1}, meta: ... ]

    return rows;

  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  } finally {
    if (db) return db.end();
  }
}

module.exports = {
  getSensorData
};
```

the output on console:

```
getConnection()..
from DB connection:
[
  {
    ID: 1,
    UID: 'e123',
    LogDate: 2023-03-23T12:30:00.000Z,
    SensorName: 'TestSensor',
    SensorValue: '28.00'
  },
  {
    ID: 2,
    UID: 'e123',
    LogDate: 2023-03-23T12:31:00.000Z,
    SensorName: 'TestSensor',
    SensorValue: '28.29'
  }
]
DB response: undefined
```

why is the data on console log inside the db query function but not after that available ?

I read about all the other Question but i dont understand clearly.
The async function is from mariadb -> get startet..
Thank you!

Comment: What do you see if you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(rows));`?

Comment: `finally { if (db) return db.end(); }` ...

Comment: won't the finally only happen on error in this case? Are you catching and logging the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the `return` statement out of the `finally` clause. It's overriding the return value of the main `try` block, since it executes whenever you leave the `try`. Since `db.end()` returns `undefined`, that's what the function returns.

```
  } finally {
    if (db) db.end();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! that was the Problem i have overseen. How can i access then easily the JSON Parts in data ... like data.ID or data.UID or data.LogDate .... ?

Comment: got it: data[0].ID ->works